# "JDODETACHEDSTATE ': identifier invalid

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

Good morning guys

Next I'm working with GWT, JPA, EclipseLink and App Engine, and I get the following exception when trying to persist in a given database:

`Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "JDODETACHEDSTATE ': identifier invalid`

Could anyone help me, I have tried to put this column as transient and did not work and finally added the following line in my entity:

`@ PersistenceCapable (identityType = IdentityType.DATASTORE, detachable = "false") also did not succeed.`

I'll be grateful for answers.

Comment: Can you share your entity that has the problem?

Comment: Hi, Chris!! I'm solved problem insert "JDODETACHEDSTATE ': identifier invalid in table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting a column is not a solution. Problem is the JDO support inserts this column in generated bytecode which works fine in case of DataStore operations. However, with mysql, the column becomes entirely irrelevant.

If you are using eclipse, go to project properties and search for app engine(mind there should be a space between app & engine). Then look for the checkbox which specifies JDO/DataNucleous support. Just uncheck it and rebuild your project. Things should be fine.